# How to create login and signup form using membership in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to authenticate user before accessing particular page, I want to do it through Membership in asp.net, Any one know the link which guide step by step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about :

[Walkthrough: Creating a Web Site with Membership and User Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx)

[ASP.NET: Adding Security and Membership](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/16-adding-security-and-membership)

Answer (score 0):

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Is this what you are looking for? It will explain everything from logins to roles etc